# @Html.DropDownListFor Options with value and text without using ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

Suppose I have a Simple table of group like in this picture,

[image]

I want to populate this as a dropdown having options `value` as `GroupID` and `Name` as `text` like shown here,

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">superadmin</option>
    <option value="2">Support Desk</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">SSL I</option>
    <option value="4">SSL II Admin</option>
    <option value="5">SSL II</option>
    <option value="6">Client</option>
</select>
```

How Can I achieve this without using ViewModels and any complexity? Actually I want to do this only using ViewBag ? Is it possible ?

**Note :** This question is only for [idea sharing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Please do not consider it as **too broad**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'm aware For sure it was possible,

**Approach 1 :**

In the view you can simply create a `Dictionary<string, string>` and those data in that `Dictionary` like here

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var allGroup = GetAllGroupNames(); //Query to get all data from table

            foreach(var ag in allGroup)
            {
                dictionary.Add(ag.GroupId.ToString(), ag.Name);

            }

            ViewBag.selectGroupList = dictionary; // Add dictionary to ViewBag

            return View();
      }
```

Then simply your `DropDownListFor` will looks like this,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, new SelectList((Dictionary<string,string>)ViewBag.selectGroupList, "Key", "Value",new { @id="dropdown"}))
```

---

**Approach 2 :**

```
 ViewBag.selectGroupList = new SelectList(GetAllGroupNames(), "GroupId", "Name");
```

and in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, (SelectList)ViewBag.selectGroupList)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Any better approaches rather than this will be appreciated**

Comment: `ViewBag.ViewBag.selectGroupList = new SelectList(GetAllGroupNames(), "GroupId", "Name");` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupId, (SelectList)ViewBag.selectGroupList)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Woooowww, That is excellency, I was sure I will get Something really useful after adding this, Really appreciate your suggestion. To be frank I'm a bit new in web development. Thank you very much for your approach, And the precious time you gave on this.

Answer (score 2):

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index() 
  {        
    var allGroup = GetAllGroupNames(); //Query to get all data from table
    ViewBag.selectGroupList = allGroup ;
    return View();
  }
```

### View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, new SelectList(ViewBag.selectGroupList, "Value", "Text",new { @id="dropdown"}))
```

Comment: yeah ! simply better !

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps....

Create an "AddressModel" class under the Models folder and create properties for label field and dropdown list values.

Model

```
public class AddressModel
{
     public AddressModel()
    {
        AvailableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    [Display(Name="Country")]
     public int CountryId { get; set; }
     public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State")]
     public int StateId { get; set; }
     public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableStates { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
   {
         AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        model.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem 
        { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });
         var countries = _repository.GetAllCountries();
         foreach (var country in countries)
        {
            model.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = country.Name,
                Value = country.Id.ToString()
            });
        }
         return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.CountryId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Controller

```
using (Context db = new Context()){
    var tmp = db.group.ToList();
    ViewBag.GroupId = new SelectList(tmp, "GroupId", "Name");
}
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupID, (SelectList)@ViewBag.GroupId)
```